# Unable save file with ofstream from sandbox virtual machine to my pc

Tags: c++

I am using

```cpp
std::ofstream saveee("C:\Users\(USERNAME)\Desktop\randomtextfile.txt", std::ofstream::trunc);
saveee << "0" << endl;
saveee.close();
```

It's not writing 0 to randomtextfile but,

```cpp
std::ofstream saveee("C:\Sandbox\(USERNAME)\newbox\randomtextfile.txt", std::ofstream::trunc);
saveee << "0" << endl;
saveee.close();
```

With this in sandbox virtual machine, when I open folders I can find this file created with 0, with loading all ok, but saving whatever I do, I can't do saving from sandbox to my pc. Is there way give permission or what more function to call to allow.

I tried checking link, maybe it's wrong, but using it directly from pc it's saving, just from sandbox I can't save to my pc...

Comment: Not being able to affect the host computer is kind of the point of a sandbox. Are you sure you're using the right technology?

Comment: @user4581301 is correct. The idea of a sandbox is to isolate it from the host so whatever happens in the sandbox can't modify or harm the host in any way. Can you please identify the sandbox software that you are using?

Comment: Some virtualisation systems allow you to share host folders with the guest - maybe this is something you need to enable & configure?

Comment: This has little to do with C++ or indeed with programming.